# Unscrew jammed plastic screw of sink basket assembly

Tags: garbage-disposal

I am trying to remove my old garbage disposal and replace it with a new one. I was able to take out the disposal but I am not able to unscrew the assembly that is attached to the sink. The assembly is jammed and when I try to unscrew (the locknut) by hitting with a hammer on its side, the whole assembly moves, including to metal part on the top part of the sink. I am looking for suggestions on how to remove it easily. Please note that I do not need the assembly to install the new disposal, so I can break it if that is easier to take the part out.

Please refer to the images attached

[image: bottom part which I am trying to unscrew]
[image: top of the sink which moves when trying to unscrew]

Comment: With one hand hold the body of the basket assembly with large channellocks, with another hand hold a long screwdriver or punch, and with your **third** hand, strike the screwdriver or punch with a hammer, against the lock-nut lugs to knock it loose!

Comment: Kidding! It is not uncommon to have to use a chisel to literally break the locknut off, be careful not to chip or crack your sink. I sometimes use a hacksaw blade to score/cut the nut first,to facilitate breaking it off.

Comment: You can actually have a second person use the *handles* of a channellock plier (spread apart some) to hold the basket from above, to keep it from spinning/moving.

Comment: The screw is really jammed. Do you think adding some kind of lubricant can help with the unscrewing?

Comment: YES, soak it with a spray penetrant and start tapping on it. Let it soak overnight if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locknut was very jammed so I ended up using a hacksaw. First, I took out the rubber washer between the sink and the locknut and cut the locknut in the space created.

[image: The basket after it was cut]